# Eclipse and Genymotion Emulator

Tags: eclipse, genymotion, eclipse-mars

I am having Eclipse MARS for Java EE with ADT plugin and with Genymotion emulator,   The problme is when I start Genymotion emulator the log cat is started to be filled with a lot of stuff starting with DHCP, Genybaseband, connectivityservice  etc etc,   Unless I start Genymotion emulator the LOG cat is clear.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What should I do now?

If I start my app it shows message that "Unfortunately the app has stopped"

Comment: search in the "lot of stuff" for your error message.